# Masstransit Azure Service Bus and DI Request/Response model

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I faced with issue of Azure Service Bus and integration with Masstransit and ASP.NET Core DI.
When i try to setup DI for **IBus** and **IRequestClient** and send message to request endpoint i get RequestTimeoutException but request endpoint get message and processed it.
When i'll try to do same using RabbitMQ or create IBus locally using Azure Service Bus, all work fine.
Issue only apply when i try to setup Azure Service Bus by ASP.NET Core DI.

Setup azure service bus:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        var bus = InitBus();

        services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(bus);
        services.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(bus);
        services.AddSingleton<IBus>(bus);

        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        var serviceAddress = new Uri("url");

        services.AddScoped<IRequestClient<SubmitOrder, OrderAccepted>>(x =>
            new MessageRequestClient<SubmitOrder, OrderAccepted>(x.GetRequiredService<IBus>(), serviceAddress, timeout, timeout));

        bus.Start();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        var bus = InitBus();

        bus.Start();

        app.UseMvc();
        //            app.Run();
    }

    public IBusControl InitBus()
    {
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(x => x.Host(new Uri(""), h =>
        {
            h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("KeyName", "KeyValue");
        }));

        return bus;
    }
}
```

Call IRequestClient

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRequestClient<SubmitOrder, OrderAccepted> _requestClient;

    public ValuesController(IRequestClient<SubmitOrder, OrderAccepted> requestClient)
    {
        _requestClient = requestClient;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            OrderAccepted result = await _requestClient.Request(new { OrderId = id });

            return Accepted(result.OrderId);
        }
        catch (RequestTimeoutException exception)
        {
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout);
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver setup:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start().Wait();
    }

    public static async Task Start()
    {
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("url"), h =>
            {
                h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("KeyName", "KeyValue=");
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "order-service", e =>
            {
                e.Handler<SubmitOrder>(context => context.RespondAsync<OrderAccepted>(new
                {
                    context.Message.OrderId
                }));
            });
        });

        await bus.StartAsync();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working....");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            await bus.StopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd suggest looking at the sample created (which uses RabbitMQ, but should easily be converted to Azure Service Bus):

https://github.com/phatboyg/Sample-DotNetCore-DI

The DI usage patterns are properly done using this sample. There are a few things about your example that aren't quite right. You're also using the legacy request client that doesn't properly capture the `ConsumeContext` for the response tracking.