# MassTransit Azure Service Bus Request-Response ASP.NET Core RequestTimeoutException

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

My goal is to make the communication between two applications (WebAPI and Worker) via MassTransit's Request/Response technique. The problem is that I'm never getting inside the consumer (request client), I'm getting a timeout instead.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625765/masstransit-azure-service-bus-and-di-request-response-model) already but the answer included a link to a github repository which no longer exists. I also tried following [a sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-DotNetCore-Request) but for some reason most samples are created as console applications which is useless for me since I have two WebAPIs trying to communicate with each other.

Anyway, here's my code:

`WebAPI.Startup`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMassTransit(massTransitConfig =>
        {
            massTransitConfig.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host("Endpoint=sb://----.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=----");
            });
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

`Worker.Startup`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMassTransit(massTransitConfig =>
        {
            massTransitConfig.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host("Endpoint=sb://----.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=----");
            });

            massTransitConfig.AddConsumer<CreateScheduleRequestClient>();
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

`WebAPI.RequestController`

```
[Route("api/requests")]
public class RequestsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

    public RequestsController(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    [HttpPost("create-schedule")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSchedule()
    {
        var client = _bus.CreateRequestClient<CreateScheduleRequest>();
        var response = await client.GetResponse<ScheduleCreatedResponse>(new CreateScheduleRequest());

        return Ok(response.Message.Succeeded);
    }
}
```

`DataTransferObjects.CreateScheduleRequest`

```
public class CreateScheduleRequest
{
    public string CommandName { get; set; }
    public string Cron { get; set; }
}
```

`Worker.RequestClients.CreateScheduleRequestClient`

```
public class CreateScheduleRequestClient : IConsumer<CreateScheduleRequest>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreateScheduleRequest> context)
    {
        await context.RespondAsync(new ScheduleCreatedResponse(true));
    }
}
```

`DataTransferObjects.ScheduleCreatedResponse`

```
public class ScheduleCreatedResponse
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; }

    public ScheduleCreatedResponse(bool succeeded)
    {
        Succeeded = succeeded;
    }
}
```

When I call the only endpoint in the `RequestsController`, I'm getting `MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: 27f60000-167b-00ff-ea0f-08d8e3a0832e` after a short period. I'm not able to verify much more about it, I thought it outght to work out of the box but perhaps I'm missing some parameters when initializing the bus in my `Startup` classes?

================EDIT================
I changed my code a little with regards to what Chris Patterson suggested and to specify that I'd like to go with the `IBus` approach. The code still throws the same exception after the change.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest reviewing the [request](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html#container-configuration) documentation, in particular the controller example that injects `IRequestClient<T>` into the controller. That will fix your controller code, which shouldn't be using `IBus`.

Second, your response should be an actual message type, it can't be `true`. You need to create a second message contract, such as `ScheduleRequestCreated` and respond with that message type. Then, your `GetResponse` would change to

`GetResponse<ScheduleRequestCreated>(new CreateScheduleRequest(...))`

And your response would be:

`RespondAsync(new ScheduleRequestCreated(...))`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll try that tomorrow in the morning. Just one question, though - why shouldn't I use `IBus`? If I had a controller that has 20 endpoints and 20 different MassTransit requests can be sent from them, I'd end up having a constructor with 20 parameters which is insane. Could you briefly explain?

Comment: That's a different situation, but given you're calling `AddRequestClient` you should use it. If you're going to create the client in the controller, don't bother registering it.

Comment: I did exactly what you described (added a response dto, used it in `GetResponse<ScheduleCreatedResponse>`, removed injection of `IBus` in the controller and replaced it with `IRequestClient<CreateScheduleRequest>`) but that did not the trick, still getting the timeout. I also tried removing injection of IRequestClient (removed `AddRequestClient` as well) and injected IBus but this approached ended up the same way. I'll update my original question with the new code (I'd rather go with the `IBus` approach)